# fancybox - navigating back and forward

Tags: jquery, fancybox, back

I'm using fancybox's ajax method to open content that itself contains a link that opens another modal in it's place. This all works fine.
My question is how can I add a "Back" functionality so that when a Back link is clicked in the currently open modal it opens the previously open modal. In this case the first modal opened?

Code so far:

```
$("a.trans").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type            : "POST",
        data            : 'mydata=test'
    },
    'padding'           : 0,
    'overlayColor'      : '#333',
    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.2
});

$("a#additional_trans").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type            : "POST",
        data            : 'mydata=test'
    },
    'padding'           : 0,
    'overlayColor'      : '#333',
    'autoDimensions'    : false,
    'titleShow'         : true,
    'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
    'title'             : 'Transact Online',
    'width'             : '633',
    'height'            : 'auto',
    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.2
});

$("#modal_back_btn").live('click', function() {
  // Not sure what to put here if indeed this is the correct place
  // It needs to open $("a.trans").fancybox() 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by

```
$.fancybox.prev();
```

However, you could also do a

```
$.fancybox.close();
$("a.trans").fancybox();
```

inside of your click handler.